# What causes undervoltage cell in a lithium ion battery pack 48v100ah?

Tags: lithium-ion, batteries, undervoltage

The lithium ion battery is composed of 15 cells. It has a battery management system. When I check the battery using the BMS app there is 1 undervoltage cell but the other 14 cells are normal. What causes it?

Comment: Unbalance in cell capacity and/or high self discharge.

Answer (score 1):

One of the cells isn't quite as good as the others.  This means that it is the one that runs flat first.  Which means that it wears more than the others, which aren't run flat every time.  Which makes that cell even less good than the others.

Repeat, to the point that that one cell fails.

Answer (score 0):

Some BMSs balance (likely resistor bleeding/bypass) cells only during charge cycles, while some balance actively (charge shuttle, pumping).
Cycle charge & discharge a few times and see if that fixes the problem (for now). If a BMS has "state of health", it will have messages around the problem. A BMS should flag errors for unreasonable/unrecoverable out-of-balance, and prevent charge/discharge operation.